# How to flatMapToLong a Stream<List<Long>>?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream, flatmap

I have this method:

```
public static long sumDigits(final List<Long> list) {
    return list
            .stream()
            .map(l -> toDigits(l))
            .flatMapToLong(x -> x.stream())
            .sum()
}
```

toDigits has this signature:

```
List<Long> toDigits(long l)
```

On the flatMapToLong line it gives this error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream< Long > to LongStream

When I change it to

```
flatMapToLong(x -> x)
```

I get this error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< Long > to LongStream

The only thing that works is this

```
public static long sumDigits(final List<Long> list) {
    return list
            .stream()
            .map(l -> toDigits(l))
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
            .reduce(0L, (accumulator, add) -> Math.addExact(accumulator, add));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Function` you pass to `flatMapToLong` needs to return a `LongStream` :

```
return list
        .stream()
        .map(l -> toDigits(l))
        .flatMapToLong(x -> x.stream().mapToLong(l -> l))
        .sum();
```

You could also split up the `flatMapToLong` if you want:

```
return list
        .stream()
        .map(ClassOfToDigits::toDigits)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
public static long sumDigits(final List<Long> list) {
    return list.stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum();
}
```